# JPA @PrePersist and @PreUpdate order when using inheritance

Tags: jpa, inheritance, callback, joined-subclass

Supposing the following code snippet which uses @PrePersist and @PreUpdate annotations and Joined-type inheritance:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class A {
    ...

    @PrePersist
    private void prePersist() {
        ...
    }

    @PreUpdate
    private void preUpdate() {
        ...
    }
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
public class B extends A {
    ...

    @PrePersist
    private void prePersist() {
        ...
    }

    @PreUpdate
    private void preUpdate() {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Question:** Can we rely on any order of execution of the callback methods?

For example when persisting class A and B will the prePersist method in B executed before the prePersist method in A or viceversa?

Can we assume that the prePersist in B will be executed before the class A is persisted?

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  First the superclass callbacks will be executed.

When an event is raised, the listeners are executed in this order:

```
@EntityListeners for a given entity or superclass in the array order

Entity listeners for the superclasses (highest first)

Entity Listeners for the entity

Callbacks of the superclasses (highest first)

Callbacks of the entity
```

For more details details read about: "Callbacks and listeners inheritance" at

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html

Comment: dont put links as it is put some important portions for the same

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was use the annotation

Example:

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AuditObject {

    @Column(name = "dat_created")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @PrePersist
    public void onPrePersist() {
        this.createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

}

@Entity
public class Person extends AuditObject {

}
```